# delayed_job_mongoid cannot use handle_asynchronously but can use .delay.method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, delayed-job

I am using Mongoid and delayed_job_mongoid gems. Everything is in its latest version, including Rails (3.2.3).

I understand that if I put handle_asynchronously after any method declaration, this method will always be run async. But I get undefined method error like this:

```
class Item
  # mongoid include stuff

  def shout
    puts 'a simple hi'
  end
  handle_asynchronously :shout
end

item = Item.create
item.shout # returns a delayed job object

j = _
# wait a moment
j.last_error 

{undefined method `shout_without_delay' for #<Item:0x007f8365e62978>
/Users/nik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongoid-2.4.9/lib/mongoid/attributes.rb:166:in `method_missing'
/Users/nik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/delayed_job-3.0.2/lib/delayed/performable_method.rb:26:in `perform'
/Users/nik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/delayed_job-3.0.2/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:94:in `block in invoke_job'
/Users/nik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/delayed_job-3.0.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `call'
/Users/nik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/delayed_job-3.0.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `block in initialize'
/Users/nik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/delayed_job-3.0.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `call'
/Users/nik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/delayed_job-3.0.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `execute'
/Users/nik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/delayed_job-3.0.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:38:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/nik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/delayed_job-3.0.2/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:91:in `invoke_job'
/Users/nik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/delayed_job-3.0.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:178:in `block (2 levels) in run'
/Users/nik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:68:in `timeout'
/Users/nik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/delayed_job-3.0.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:178:in `block in run'
/Users/nik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
```

BUT if I had called

```
item.delay.shout
```

without the handle_asynchronously line

it will work!

Any ideas?
THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the author of the post. I found out what happened. Short answer: You have to restart the workers in the terminal

```
[control + c]
rake jobs:work
```

for mongoid delay jobs to be able to find the method. I do not know why. So just remember to restart the workers whenever you have added another line of handle_asynchronously :method

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You syntax should be

```
class Item
   # mongoid include stuff

   def shout
      puts 'a simple hi'
   end
   handle_asynchronously :shout
end
```

you can get more details from here https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job